# Nodejs -- Cannot read property 'findAll' of undefined

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I'm using nodejs with sequelize and connecting to a postgres database.

I have created a model and inside one of my routes I'm trying to return all of the users within the database.

The code:

routes.js

```
var models = require('../server/models/index');
router.get('/users', function(req, res, next) {

    models.Users.findAll({}).then(function(user) {

    });
});
```

/server/models/index

```
'use strict';

var fs        = require('fs');
var path      = require('path');
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var basename  = path.basename(module.filename);
var env       = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
var config    = require(__dirname + '/../config.json')[env];
var db        = {};

if (config.use_env_variable) {
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable]);
} else {
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(function(file) {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename);
  })
  .forEach(function(file) {
    if (file.slice(-3) !== '.js') return;
    var model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(function(modelName) {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

I am getting the following when running the server and navigating to it:

`Cannot read property 'findAll' of undefined`

I have tested the connection and it's all working fine. I cannot seem to figure out what is going wrong here. Any ideas to what I'm missing?

EDIT:

users.js

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Users = sequelize.define('users', {
    email: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        // associations can be defined here
      }
    }
  });
  return Users;
};
```

Comment: do you have users.js somewhere there?

Comment: @Adam Popkiewicz I have just updated my question. Please see edit

Comment: not sure, maybe capital U `var Users =  sequelize.define('Users', {`

Comment: @AdamPopkiewicz New error if I do what you say: "Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: relation "Users" does not exist" -- But the table "users" exists

Comment: @Phorce, can you pls explain what's behind the code `var model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file))` and what's the result for `console.log(model)` ?

Comment: @RashadIbrahimov I forgot to mention: This is taken from.. http://mherman.org/blog/2015/10/22/node-postgres-sequelize/#.WKQ7VxKLRTb but not using their boiler plating as per

Comment: @RashadIbrahimov The output is just: `users`

Comment: @RashadIbrahimov Weird, if I run a migration then it works just fine. The problem is that I do not need to run migrations, another part of the application handles this..

Comment: Your model is not recognize

Comment: You should load model file from current directory, add them to the db. Try console.log modelName in the loop what you get.

Comment: @Phorce, can you expand pls your answer, what do you mean by saying "output: users", is it just a string, or is it an object, can you provide full output of `console.log(model)` ?

Comment: @Phorce, what's the version of sequelize?

Comment: @RashadIbrahimov - The migration has now fixed the problem.. I don't know why but creating a model and running a migration fixes it. (Even though there is table in there)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of sequelize.define('users');

Try var Users = sequelize.define('Users'); or var Users = sequelize.define('User');

Answer (score 1):

when you are using the sequelize model you need to use the defined model class name.

```
var models = require('../server/models');
router.get('/users', function(req, res, next) {

    models.Users.findAll({}).then(function(user) {

    });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

model
var user = sequelize.define('userModel');

router
wrong : models.**userModel**.findAll({}).then